How to configure log4j for Kafka Consumers in Kafka 3.8.0
I'm trying to enable the logging for Kafka Producers & Consumers using log4j in kafka 3.8.0, to maintain the logs whenever the new producer or consumer connects. So, I was overriding the log4j.properties file by using the ENV variable KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS and setting new location for log4j file. I can see the broker logs but it does not have logs for kafka consumers.
KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS: "- 
Dlog4j.configuration=file:/etc/kafka/log4j.properties"  
KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /var/lib/kafka/data

volumes:

./etc/kafka/log4j.properties:/etc/kafka/log4j.properties
kafka-log:/var/log/kafka

I have updated the log4j.properties file with the below settings. Please guide me with the solution, to implement logging for Kafka Consumers.
Log4j.properties file
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, kafkaAppender
……


# Change the two lines below to adjust the general broker logging level (output to server.log and stdout)
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=INFO

# Change to DEBUG or TRACE to enable request logging
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=DEBUG, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.request.logger=true

# Uncomment the lines below and change log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$ to TRACE for additional output
# related to the handling of requests
log4j.logger.kafka.network.Processor=TRACE, requestAppender
log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaApis=TRACE, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.server.KafkaApis=true
log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=TRACE, requestAppender
log4j.additivity.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=false


# Enable logging for new producer / consumer group
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.common.requests.ProduceRequest=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.producer=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer=INFO
log4j.logger.kafka.coordinator.group=INFO
log4j.logger.kafka.network.ConnectionHandler=INFO
log4j.logger.kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler=INFO



for Kafka Consumers

Every option you've shown is for brokers. You've not shown your consumer code, and consumers aren't required to use Java. Plus, you shouldn't be using log4j 1.x, anyway (ref Log4Shell). For example, Spring Boot + Spring-kafka would use logback, by default
Regarding the broker, you shouldn't need to override KAFKA_LOG4J_OPTS, as the file reference is automatically set
